# How to make expressjs support batch request like facebook

Tags: node.js, express

I have a set of routes with different methods. I want to make the expressjs to support batch request which is very similar to facebook, [Facebook Batch Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). Does anybody know how to do it? And I dont want to make 3 loopback connections for handling the batch request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to make loopback connections, then the simplest solution is to manually call your server with fake requests.

You'll have to reimplement [IncomingMessage](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_incoming.js). You should also use [Async#map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) to wait until all requests are processed.

Here's the basic idea:

```
// You'll probably have more work to do to reimplement http basic API.
function FakeRequest(request) {
  this.url = '/' + request.relative_url;
  this.method = request.method;
  this.headers = request.headers;
}

function FakeResponse() {
  Stream.call(this);

  this.statusCode = null;
  this.body = '';
}

FakeResponse.prototype.write = function (chunk) {
  this.body += chunk.toString('utf8');

  return true;
};

util.inherits(FakeResponse, Stream);

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var requests = JSON.parse(req.body.batch);

  async.map(requests, function (request, done) {
    var fakeReq = new FakeRequest(request),
        fakeRes = new FakeResponse();

    // call Express' middleware manually
    app(fakeReq, fakeRes);

    // this will trigger when the response is ready.
    fakeRes.once('end', function () {
      // don't leak listeners
      fakeRes.removeAllListeners();
      done(null, fakeRes);
    });

    fakeRes.once('error', function (err) {
      fakeRes.removeAllListeners();
      done(err);
    });
  }, function (err, responses) {
    if (err)
      return res.send(err);

    res.send(responses);
  });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**UPDATE**

I'm actually not sure what you mean by loopback, but you have 2 options:

- Open an HTTP connection for each request in the batch, which is easier to implement but slower.
- The solution I outlined above: call the Express middleware directly without opening HTTP requests.

I was under the impression that you didn't want the first solution. However, that's what I would try first, even if it's slower:

- Easier to spread your batch connections across multiple instances when you scale.
- You won't bypass any load throttling mechanism you might have (that prevent a single Express instance from processing too many requests simultaneously).

Be sure to disable the [HTTP Agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) though.

Comment: Thanks! Before trying, I have still another questions. Do you think loopback connections approach is better than traditional http request approach in performance? To me yes. I want to know your answer. if they are no differences, I will just use the traditional one with Async#map

Comment: I tried using this method with Express framework but found that it fails with "res.status is not a function"