# Processing Batch REST API requests in NodeJS Express framework

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, mean-stack

I am trying to implement batch API for my application, and the client can send a send a set of request to server and expects a single response back.

Using Express framework in my MEAN stack app. I have created a batch API resource that receives this from client and should act as per the URL mentioned in each part of the request.

Sample Request Body:

```
{
    "batchID": "abc123",
    "batchReq": [{
        "id": "1",
        "url": "/api/schoolm/students",
        "method": "GET",
        "value": null
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "url": "/api/schoolm/teachers",
        "method": "POST",
        "value": {
            "name": "Teacher1",
            "age": 34
        }
    }]
}
```

This is sent to /api/schoolm/batch

How can I redirect the requests each from inside the batch controller to their respective API?

Comment: what is the motivation of having 1 request be divided into multiple request?

Comment: This isn't one request - they are of different types meant for different APIs. Having them clubbed in one request is to reduce the number of calls I want to make from my client side of the code.

Comment: i believe your approach may not be correct, are you worried if node can't handle the amount of requests you expect?, as a single instance of node is more than capable of handling most loads , if it cant you can scale up using clusters which is very easy in node as well

Comment: Oh, no. That's not a problem. We don't expect that high a traffic. But giving every flexibility to UI should they need data from multiple APIs to display on one screen. Those for example, can be clubbed into one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is heavily borrowed/inspired/taken from [clay's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3018068/clay) response. And I am just adding all the details that I have used in my case. Thank you again clay!

First here's how my API is structured:

`/api/schoolm` is the parent api

And from there requests are redirected to child APIs:

```
/api/schoolm/students/
/api/schoolm/teachers/
/api/schoolm/subjects/
...
```

Now, to support batch opertaions, I added another API which would be responsible to handle all batch transactions.

```
/api/schoolm/batch/
```

A typical batch request would look like:

```
{
"batchReq":[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "uri": "/api/schoolm/students/",
    "httpMethod": "GET"
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "uri": "/api/schoolm/teachers/",
    "httpMethod": "GET"
  }
]
}
```

The controller at `/api/schoolm/batch` validates the request (business logic) and responds back with a reference ID.

```
var async = require('async');
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
var shortid = require('shortid');

exports.processBatch = function(batchRequests, callback){


  var batchRes = {};
  var result = {};

  var batchID = shortid.generate();
  result.batchID = batchID;

  async.setImmediate(function () {
    async.eachSeries(batchRequests, function(batchReq, callback){
      var mockRes = httpMocks.createResponse({
        eventEmitter: require('events').EventEmitter
      });

      var reqDetails = _processSubRequest(batchReq);

      _fetchResponse(reqDetails, mockRes);
      mockRes.on('end',function(){
        result[batchReq.id] = mockRes._getData();
        callback(null);
      });

    },function(err){
      console.log(result);
    });
  });

  callback("Your batch request has been accepted. Request ID - "+batchID);
}

function _processSubRequest(batchReq){
  var retValue = {};
  var request = {};
  var uriComp = batchReq.uri.split('/');
  retValue.controller = uriComp[3];

  request.method = batchReq.httpMethod;
  request.url = batchReq.uri;
  request.body = batchReq.body || {};
  request.params = batchReq.params || {};

  if(batchReq.httpMethod == 'GET'){
      if(uriComp.length > 5){
        request.params.id = uriComp[4];
      }
  }else if(batchReq.httpMethod == 'POST'){

  }else{

  }
  retValue.request = request;
  return retValue;
}

function _fetchResponse(reqDetails, mockRes){
   var mockReq  = httpMocks.createRequest(reqDetails.request);
   // proceed to fetch answer from respective controller methods.
   .......................
}

function _prepResponse(result, err, res){
  var data = {};

  if(err) {
    data["error"] = err;
    data["response"] = null;
    return data;
  }else{
    data["error"] = null;
    data["response"] = result;
    return data;
  }
}
```

After the batch processing completes, it can be sent to the user as part of live notification or stored in DB to be read from later.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to double-define your routing tables. You could break up your logic a bit so you have easier access to the functions. Define a `StudentsController` and `TeacherController`, so you can define Express routes like

```
app.get('/api/schoolm/students', studentController.getStudents );
app.post('/api/schoolm/teachers', teachController.postTeachers );
```

but still access them in your batching method. **EDIT:** You probably want to break apart the main logic even more, so you can just call the batching methods directly.

```
StudentController.prototype.getStudents = function(params, callback){
  //do stuff
  callback( null, studentList );
}

StudenController.prototype.getStudentsRequest = function( req, res ){
  this.getStudents( {}, function( err, students ){
    //check error
    res.send( students );
  });
}

//elsewhere, in routing table
app.get('/api/schoolm/students', studentController.getStudentsRequest );

//elsewhere, in batching method
//api route that matches students
studentController.getStudents( batchReq[index].value, function(err, students){
  //do something with students, like put in outer results object.
  //call async.each's callback(), or whatever for control flow
} );
```

Alternatively, you could make fake `req` and `res` objects to call the controllers directly. Something like [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http).

Of course, you'd have to re-parse the paths named in the batching object so you can call the correct controller method and store up the results. Maybe something like [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) (or whatever express uses internally) would help.

Your typical routes in Express would send their response at the end, and that `res.send` could call `res.end` as well, so you can't really pass them around or use them elsewhere (as you cannot call `res.end` twice).

Though really, why not just send multiple requests from the client. Then you don't have to parse out a batch response on the client as well. I think that will make your

Comment: I am curious how google processes it's batch APIs wanted to apply something similar. Even Salesforce does it.

But all they have is how the client request should be sent, no one talks about how it is processed in the backend.

Comment: In the end you'll have to call the correct function for each item in the batch, which is basically just regex parsing. If you have path parameters, you'd want something like director or [route-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/route-parser) to make that easier. Careful of how long batches take to process (or how many items can exist in the batch) so the original request doesn't time out while waiting.

Comment: Have taken care of that part, async processing and a notification mechanish to notify user about the end of the process.

Comment: I was looking at batch processing because once I have all requests in one shot, I just need to call local methods instead of HTTP methods like the client would have done.

Comment: Sounds like you got it. Hopefully this was a helpful answer to you.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow, and update you. Thank you so much!

Comment: I took a hint from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942289/how-to-make-expressjs-support-batch-request-like-facebook but there's one problem.. The controller methods accept request and response method as parameters which I don't have, I tried generating like the above link but that fails with an error saying "res.status is not a function".

Comment: I updated my answer to mention a way to break apart the logic. The package [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http) could be helpful for you as well, depending which way you want to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much @clay I was able to achieve this. Will post my answer, you have helped a lot. I just built everything around it to suit express framework.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `GraphQL` for batch request :)