# Sending response to a single request in batch mern

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have like /1000+ users and want to send them in response to a single get request to show these users in admin panel table
Is these any way so that I can return response to a Single request in batch of 100 users per batch

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would have explained more, but it is summarized pretty good here:

[Processing Batch REST API requests in NodeJS Express framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593348/processing-batch-rest-api-requests-in-nodejs-express-framework)

see swateek comment.

If you don't understand comment here and I will help.